# Larger delay on first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im having problems delaying the first run of a function. I've created a very simple slideshow but because of that I'm having problems delaying the first run.

I want the first run to wait 10 seconds and then keep the 4 second delay between the rest of the images.

This is my code:

```
function slideshow() {

    $("#slideshow .slide:hidden:first").fadeIn(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
        slideshow();
    });

}

$(document).ready( function () {

    $("#slideshow .slide").hide();
    slideshow();

});
```

I've tried a few different things but none successful.

I don't think jsfiddle is needed on this issue but if you want it just comment and i'll set it up!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for Javascript's built-in `setTimeout` function, it creates a timer and executes the passed code after the timer finishes. In your $(document).ready() you can try this:

```
 setTimeout( slideshow, 10000);
```

This will delay the execution of your `slideshow` function for 10 seconds. [Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

Use a timeout on the first call to your slideshow function. [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) accepts the second parameter as the amount of milliseconds to wait before executing the code in the argument. 10,000 milliseconds is 10 seconds.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#slideshow .slide").hide();
    setTimeout(function(){slideshow();},10000);
});
```